# R/gtsummary: excluding outliers in tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is it possible to have `gtsummary::tbl_summary` compute the mean excluding outliers? For example in the following code I present sample data of some z-scores. Is it possible to specify what, or add a clause, to how `gtsummary::tbl_summary` handles each column?

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                  treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                  outcome1=runif(n, min=-3.6, max=2.3),
                  outcome2=runif(n, min=-1.9, max=3.3),
                  outcome3=runif(n, min=-2.5, max=2.8),
                  outcome4=runif(n, min=-3.1, max=2.2))
dat %>% select(-c(id)) %>% tbl_summary(by=treat, statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({min} to {max})"))
```

For example, suppose I want the table to report the mean of `outcome1`only in cases where `outcome1 >= -2.9` and for `outcome2` only when cases are `outcome2 < 3.0` etc.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new mean function that excludes outlying values. You can define the outlier in any way you'd like. Then pass that function to `tbl_summary()`. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                  treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                  outcome1=runif(n, min=-3.6, max=2.3),
                  outcome2=runif(n, min=-1.9, max=3.3),
                  outcome3=runif(n, min=-2.5, max=2.8),
                  outcome4=runif(n, min=-3.1, max=2.2))

mean_no_extreme <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mean <- mean(x)
  
  # calculate mean excluding extremes
  mean(x[x >= mean - sd * 3 & x <= mean + sd * 3])
}


dat %>% 
  select(-c(id)) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=treat, 
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean_no_extreme} ({min} to {max})"
  ) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Control**, N = 527 | **Treat**, N = 473 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| outcome1 | -0.64 (-3.59 to 2.30) | -0.70 (-3.60 to 2.30) |
| outcome2 | 0.68 (-1.89 to 3.30) | 0.78 (-1.87 to 3.28) |
| outcome3 | 0.20 (-2.47 to 2.80) | 0.23 (-2.48 to 2.80) |
| outcome4 | -0.36 (-3.09 to 2.19) | -0.41 (-3.10 to 2.20) |

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your solution! Always so helpful and elegant

Comment: Hi @Daniel D. Sjoberg, further to the above code, is it possible to have the 95%CI for the ```all_continuous()``` call?