# r/gtsummary: Creating a function so that tbl_summary reports 95%CI of selected data

Tags: r, function, gtsummary

Further to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571603/r-gtsummary-excluding-outliers-in-tbl-summary), I am seeking assistance to have the `all_continuous()` call report the 95%CI of the previously selected data.

```
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                  treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                  outcome1=runif(n, min=-3.6, max=2.3),
                  outcome2=runif(n, min=-1.9, max=3.3),
                  outcome3=runif(n, min=-2.5, max=2.8),
                  outcome4=runif(n, min=-3.1, max=2.2))

mean_no_extreme <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mean <- mean(x)
  
  # calculate mean excluding extremes
  mean(x[x >= mean - sd * 3 & x <= mean + sd * 3])
}

lci <- function(x){
  x <- na.omit(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mean <- mean_no_extreme(x)
  e <- (mean*sd)/(sqrt(n))
  (x[x=mean-e*1.96])
}

uci <- function(x){
  x <- na.omit(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mean <- mean_no_extreme(x)
  e <- (mean*sd)/(sqrt(n))
  (x[x=mean+e*1.96])
}


dat %>% 
  select(-c(id)) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=treat, 
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean_no_extreme} ({lci} to {uci})"
  ) %>%
  as_kable()
```

Any guidance is tremendously appreciated.

Many thanks,
Sandro

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in your CI calculation functions. Here's an example that runs without error.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                  treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
                  outcome1=runif(n, min=-3.6, max=2.3),
                  outcome2=runif(n, min=-1.9, max=3.3),
                  outcome3=runif(n, min=-2.5, max=2.8),
                  outcome4=runif(n, min=-3.1, max=2.2))

.remove_extremes <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mean <- mean(x)
  
  x[x >= mean - sd * 3 & x <= mean + sd * 3]
}

mean_no_extreme <- function(x) {
  mean(.remove_extremes(x))
}

conf.low.no_extreme <- function(x) {
  .remove_extremes(x) |> t.test() |> broom::tidy() |> purrr::pluck("conf.low")
}

conf.high.no_extreme <- function(x) {
  .remove_extremes(x) |> t.test() |> broom::tidy() |> purrr::pluck("conf.high")
}


dat %>% 
  select(-c(id)) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=treat,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean_no_extreme} ({conf.low.no_extreme} to {conf.high.no_extreme})"
  ) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Control**, N = 527 | **Treat**, N = 473 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| outcome1 | -0.64 (-0.79 to -0.49) | -0.70 (-0.86 to -0.54) |
| outcome2 | 0.68 (0.55 to 0.81) | 0.78 (0.64 to 0.91) |
| outcome3 | 0.20 (0.07 to 0.34) | 0.23 (0.09 to 0.37) |
| outcome4 | -0.36 (-0.49 to -0.23) | -0.41 (-0.54 to -0.27) |

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: SO can always rely on your solutions! Thank you. Can you explain how your functions work to calculate the 95%CI? I'm not sure I understand what the ```t.test()``` is doing there and for ```purrr:pluck()``` from where is it 'plucking' the conf.int?

Comment: Further, if I add in ```add_difference(everything() ~ "t.test"``` it seems to be computing this on the whole vector and not the specified subset of outliers removed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can write custom methods for `add_difference()` that can exclude extremes as you need. For the methods in `t.test()`, you'll want to review the function's documentaton.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel. As you can tell, I know a bit but clearly not enough in how to manipulate ```function(x)``` for my needs. Are you able to provide any guidance on what this may look like?

Comment: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html